# RTRIM & LTRIM Function with Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i use the LTRIM & RTRIM with the following SQL? I need to LTRIM and RTRIM all these fields for leading spaces

```
UPDATE CORE.WeccoPartyAddress 
SET AddressElements = CONTROL.TrimChar(
                                   CASE when COALESCE(Address1,'') != '' THEN Address1 + ', ' ELSE '' END +
                                   CASE when COALESCE(Address2,'') != '' THEN Address2 + ', ' ELSE '' END +
                                   CASE when COALESCE(Address3,'') != '' THEN Address3 + ', ' ELSE '' END +
                                   CASE when COALESCE(Town,'') != '' THEN Town + ', ' ELSE '' END +
                                   CASE when COALESCE(County,'') != '' THEN County + ', ' ELSE '' END +
                                   CASE when COALESCE(Postcode,'') != '' THEN Postcode ELSE '' END, ', '
                                  )
```

Comment: `CONTROL.TrimChar()` isn't a valid T-SQL. What is that? (It looks like you're mixing T-SQL and C#.) Have you looked up the syntax for `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`? What don't you understand about their usage?

Comment: ^ Most likely. Maybe he wants to trim the value from the input field in the form before passing to the SQL query.

Comment: yeah i want to trim it from input fields before it is passed to the sql

Comment: In that case you need to provide your C# code where in you are calling the SQL query, setting the parameters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use like below nested:

```
UPDATE CORE.WeccoPartyAddress SET AddressElements = rtrim(ltrim(CASE when COALESCE(Address1,'') != '' THEN Address1 + ', ' ELSE '' END + CASE when COALESCE(Address2,'') != '' THEN Address2 + ', ' ELSE '' END + CASE when COALESCE(Address3,'') != '' THEN Address3 + ', ' ELSE '' END + CASE when COALESCE(Town,'') != '' THEN Town + ', ' ELSE '' END + CASE when COALESCE(County,'') != '' THEN County + ', ' ELSE '' END + CASE when COALESCE(Postcode,'') != '' THEN Postcode ELSE '' END))
```

Comment: this says "The ltrim function requires 1 argument" when i run it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `CASE` in your statement

```
UPDATE CORE.WeccoPartyAddress
SET AddressElements = ISNULL( STUFF (
    COALESCE( ', ' + LTRIM( RTRIM(Address1) )           , '') +
    COALESCE( ', ' + LTRIM( RTRIM(Address1Address2) )   , '') +
    COALESCE( ', ' + LTRIM( RTRIM(Address1Address3) )   , '') +
    COALESCE( ', ' + LTRIM( RTRIM(Address1Town) )       , '') +
    COALESCE( ', ' + LTRIM( RTRIM(Address1County) )     , '') +
    COALESCE( ', ' + LTRIM( RTRIM(Address1Postcode) )   , '')
    ,1
    ,2
    ,''
    ), '')
```

---

If any of Address values is not null you will get string like this: ', Address', then using the function [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you replace ', ' at the beginning of the string to get 'Address' as the result.

If all values are null the STUFF function will return NULL which will be replaced with '' by [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what this piece of SQL does? I have never used this before

Comment: @Simulator23, I have added some explanation.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin.. no need of `', '` for `Address1`. I think so..!

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish, no, it does need

Comment: why..? `Address` is First Address. Then, why it needs `', '` at the beginning.?

Comment: Because of using the STUFF function to remove two first symbols

Comment: @DenisRubashkin `select isnull('address1'+', '+'address2'+', '+'address3'+', '+'city', '')`... Here, I dont add `', '` before the `address1`.. So `stuff()` is not used.

Comment: What do you want to convince me of? Imagine in your example city = '', so which result will you get? What would you do with the last comma which had to be between address3 and city but city turned out to be empty? I handle the excess comma by using the STUFF function, if you know another better way feel free to add your own answer which will be appreciated I'm sure.